# Derivative of absolutely integrable functions

Tags: calculus

Is it necessary for an absolutely integrable function to have an absolutely integrable derivative?
Suppose we have $$\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}|f(x)|dx<\infty$$
Does this imply $$\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}|f'(x)|dx<\infty$$?

Comment: No. It could not have a derivative in the first place.

Comment: @Gae.S. Could you please give an example?

Comment: I know I'm going to regret this, but name three absolutely integrable functions on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: You're right, will delete comment. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) $f$ is continuous and nowhere-differentiable. Further, it is bounded in absolute value by $\sum_n a^n$.
Therefore $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |e^{-x^2}f(x)|\,dx$$ converges, but $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x^2}f(x)\right)$$ fails to exist anywhere.